# How to convert a 'for' loop into a matricial expression for a list of lists using python3?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to convert a `for` loop into an expression using matrix form. I have a list of lists, a list of indices, and a matrix of shape (4,2) named 'toSave':

```
import numpy as np

M = [list() for i in range(3)]
indices= [1,1,0,1]
toSave = np.array([[0, 0],
                   [0, 1],
                   [0, 2],
                   [0, 3]])
```

for each index `i` in indices i want to save the row corresponding to the position of index `i` in indices:

```
for n, i in enumerate(indices):
    M[i].append(toSave[n])
```

the result is:

```
M=[[[0, 2]], [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 3]], []]
```

Is possible to use a matricial expression instead to use a `for` loop, something as `M[indices].append(toSave[range(4)])` ?

Comment: What are the `indices` doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
sidx = np.argsort(indices)
s_indx = np.take(indices, sidx)

split_idx = np.flatnonzero(s_indx[1:] != s_indx[:-1])+1
out = np.split(toSave[sidx], split_idx, axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
# Given inputs
In [67]: M=[[] for i in range(3)]
    ...: indices= [1,1,0,1]
    ...: toSave=np.array([[0, 0],
    ...:        [0, 1],
    ...:        [0, 2],
    ...:        [0, 3]])
    ...: 

# Using loopy solution
In [68]: for n, i in enumerate(indices):
    ...:     M[i].append(toSave[n])
    ...:     

In [69]: M
Out[69]: [[array([0, 2])], [array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 3])], []]

# Using proposed solution
In [70]: out
Out[70]: 
[array([[0, 2]]), array([[0, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 3]])]
```

**Performance boost**

A faster way would be to avoid `np.split` and do the splitting with [`slicing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), like so -

```
sorted_toSave = toSave[sidx]
idx = np.concatenate(( [0], split_idx, [toSave.shape[0]] ))
out = [sorted_toSave[i:j] for i,j in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])]
```

Comment: Thanks Divakar. I understand that with  the `slicing` is faster but i'm try to avoid any kind of `for` loop. Only one question: how can i update a previusly M list with the matrix just created: image that a M is not empty but is equal to the last we have computed: `M=[[array([0, 2])], [array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 3])], []]`, with the same indices and with the loop solution i will get `M=[[array([0, 2]), array([0, 2])], [array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 3]), array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 3])], []]`

Comment: @GiuseppeAngora If you are trying to update an already created `M` list, don't use this method. On the issue of using for-loop, there's no avoiding for-loops given that you have a ragged number of sublists at each index. You can only have "better for-loops" that do things more efficiently than others by doing most of the things before going into the loop.